# My tsconfig in my module folder does not override the extended tsconfig peoperty values in the parent folder

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have a `tsconfig.json` in the parent folder `store/aisle/fruits`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    .
    .
    "target": "es6",
    "noEmitOnError" : true,
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "stripInternal": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "declaration": true
  }
}
```

And I have another `tsconfig.json` in `store/aisle/fruits/mango` to override the target property. `Price.ts` has an `async/await` implementation and I want it to remain as such in the generated `.js` files; hence, changing `target` value to `ES2017`:

```
{
  "extends": '../tsconfig',
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017"
  },
  "files": ["Price.ts", "index.ts"]
}
```

For some reason, however, the `tsc` does not seem to catch the changes in the `tsconfig` in the `mango` folder and override the `tsconfig` in the `fruits` folder. Therefore, the generated `.js` includes the emitted helpers (`__awaiter`), which I do not want.

So, my question is how can I override the target value to get the desired effect (having only the `async/await` and not `__awaiter`) in my `price.js` file?

Comment: My understanding is that tsconfig files do not act like eslint configurations. When you run `tsc` you must pick one, and only one, configuration file for the entire build. The `extends` property allows your chosen tsconfig file to inherit properties from one or more other JSON files, but your `mango/tsconfig` file will be ignored if you've chosen to use the `fruits/tsconfig` during your build.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a solution to actually build **child** `tsconfig.json` in each project `extends` **parents** `tsconfig.json` is running `tsc` bulding in each **child** `tsconfig.json` that extends the parent one.

In order to do this dynamically we can use npm workspaces.

Example project

```bash
.
├── module-a
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── package.json  // child package json that contains its own script build
│   └── tsconfig.json // child tsconfig
│
├── module-b
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── package.json  // child package json that contains its own script build
│   └── tsconfig.json // child tsconfig
│
├── package.json      // parent package.json workspace
└── tsconfig.json // parent tscongig
```

parent `./package.json` workspace

```json
{
  "name": "workspace-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "workspaces": [
        "module-a", 
        "module-b"
  ]
}
```

child `./module-a/package.json` module-a

```json
{
    "name": "module-a",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "build" : "tsc" // could be any command
    }
}
```

parent `./tsconfig.json` ( contains all options to be overrided )

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "outDir": "build",
        "target": "ES2017",
      },
      "compileOnSave": true  
}
```

child `./module-a/tsconfig.json`

```json
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "build-module-a", // overriding
        "sourceMap": "true",  // overriding
    }
}
```

In order to build each modules separately run on root folder workspace:

```
npm run build --workspaces
```

build specific module

```
npm run build --workspace=module-a
```

Note:
Running `npm install` will install all modules in one `node_modules` folder